# using path in other computer

Tags: sql, database, winforms, sqlite

How can I use my database with another computer without changing the path?

I'm using this path

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(
"data source=C:\\Users\\users\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\SKM Computerized Payroll System\\db_SKMPayroll.sqlite");
```

Comment: By ensuring that the same path exists on the other computer. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: when my program is in exe file the it will not read the program on other computer unless i change the path on that computer

Comment: Learn how to use `=@"data source=C:\Users\users\ ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the path you are now using for your database file. It is a location used to store your VS project in development. When you deploy your application, you should not use any of your development folders.

You should use a dedicated folder for your database, like
`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`
`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)`

Or you can [use the folder your app is installed in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7358644/2224701), provided that the every user has read/write access to it (it should not be e.g. in `ProgramFiles`)

Try this one:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(
 string.Format(
   "data source={0}", 
   Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                "db_SKMPayroll.sqlite"))
```

If you use a database file stored in your `\bin\Debug` or `\bin\Release` folder [using CopyAllways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465298(v=vs.100).aspx), be prepared that your development database in `\bin\` folders gets ovewriten with the database file from your project.