# Deploy all content of /public directory in Visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm using a build process that create hashed `js` and `css` files. As these files are builded, they aren't versionned, and they aren't included in the VS project.

I'd like them to be published with the application when using the VS publish to web.

How can I tell VS 2012 to include all the content in the public folder (even if not included in the project) on publish?

Comment: Did you try setting the build action for each item to Content?

Comment: The files aren't created when the deploy process is launched, and the files are simply .js and .css.

Comment: If you want them included in the build which then includes them in the output they should have their build action set to Content. Then when deployment kicks in they are there. Visual Studio uses web deploy in the background so if the files are in the correct location that web deploy pulls from they should be synced.

Comment: And how can I set the build action to content? I set this on a folder?

Comment: First make sure that the files are part of the project (i.e. show in the list). Next open the Properties dialog (F4). Select each file in the project you want to keep (one by one) and choose Content for Build Action.

Comment: That don't work for me because content is dynamically created. Here is the answer I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059562/in-visual-studio-how-can-i-set-the-build-action-for-an-entire-folder Thanks for your help though, you pointed me in the good direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, you need to add a config to your `.csproj` config.

Inside `<Project>`, simply add a target:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="public\**\*.*">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```