# Visual Studio - Items within folder - Can all items in folder always have property of embedded resource always?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a console application with a folder.  This folder contains files that are added to it on a daily basis.  In order for this application to be executed at a later date these files need to be marked as embedded resources.  As this application is packaged up.

Is there anyway to have all items in a folder marked as an embedded resource?  Either automatically or programatically?  Basically, I just want to make sure if an item is added to this folder it is automatically included as an embedded resource.

I know how to right click, properties, set a file as an embedded resource, but others tend to forget to do this which causes research back down the chain etc.

Comment: You'll have to edit the `.csproj`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Visual Studio, how can I set the Build Action for an entire folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059562/in-visual-studio-how-can-i-set-the-build-action-for-an-entire-folder)?

Comment: Looks like that would work.  Would you like to answer my question so I can mark that as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059562/in-visual-studio-how-can-i-set-the-build-action-for-an-entire-folder).

Basically, you want to edit the `.csproj` file manually to do something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="myfolder**\*.dll**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So you'll want to use wildcards (`*`) to match the folder name.

Comment: Thanks just figured this might be a more searchable subject line.