# In Visual Studio, how I can select more than one file at once?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide

I have to change "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if Newer" in every file, I have more than 1000 files, how I can select all of them and change it?

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/3334a85d521f77aed6d931b193a1b2f6.png]

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/80df7f80b9044fda3688a8cf45fc354d.png]

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059562/in-visual-studio-how-can-i-set-the-build-action-for-an-entire-folder

Comment: In that case you could run a search-and-replace on your .csproj or run it through an xslt. Ctrl + clicking to select them would still take ages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the files in the solution explorer that you need to change using CTRL and/or SHIFT and then change the property.

Comment: Will work, though I wonder how long it will take the properties window to load for > 1000 items!

Comment: Thanks man, the Shift allows you to select it all! (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @stuartd doesn't take long because it's still the same window and it only exposes a subset of properties when multiple files are selected (sorry didn't mean to ignore you...)

Comment: Done! Im new here.

Comment: no worries mate, that's why I mentioned it, in case you didn't know :)