# Using hashed bundles in a .Net project

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, webpack

So the .Net project uses a .csproj file to keep track of files that are included in project which eventually make it's way on prod. Having a webpack configuration that bundles the JS and CSS and also moves all assets into a /media folder, all with a hash how it's possible to "include" those files in the project in an automatic way. Maybe by reading an `asset-manifest.json` file or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Working with MVC applications for example you can configure webpack to output the bundle in your scripts/dist folder and your mvc app can referrence this one. 
Other option if you need advanced scenario is using gulp to copy files / clean / whatever.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059562/in-visual-studio-how-can-i-set-the-build-action-for-an-entire-folder this solution works for what I wanted to achieve, thanks for help