# How to include folders and files in AppX for UWP application?

Tags: c#, deployment, uwp, package, post-build-event

I have an UWP application which contains multiple UWP projects and some win32 projects(win form, wpf etc.). After deployment, I want to see my win32 binaries copied to AppX folder, how could I do that? Do I use post build or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `Build Action: Content`:

[image: build action: content]

select an entry in visual studio to see the menu below. Normally you would do this with images or other resources.

To set the build action for the whole folder(s) you can refer to [In Visual Studio, how can I set the Build Action for an entire folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059562/in-visual-studio-how-can-i-set-the-build-action-for-an-entire-folder)

Comment: My win32 project depends on a lot of third party binaries, and those binaries keep updated. Is there a way, I can set build action to content to all items in a folder? It is hard to add all third party binaries as content of the win32 project one by one, there are too many. I wonder is there a better way to include a whole folder as part of the AppX package.

Comment: Mabye there is another way altogether; what are you trying to archieve?

Comment: I want to set the Win32 folder as content, so it includes whatever files, binaries etc. under the folder Win32 in AppX folder. I don't want to add those files, binaries one by one.

Comment: This I understood; but why do you want those files there in the first place? Mabye there is a better way to solve your initial problem

Comment: I have an old wpf project, it refers to third party libraries which keep updated. Now we want this wpf application to be part of our new UWP project, so we convert it by copy all output of the wpf application along with the third party libraries to the UWP project sub folder Win32. After doing that, I deploy the application, but all the binaries of wpf and third party libraries are not under AppX folder. If I manually copy the folder Win32 and its content to AppX folder, my applications work.

Comment: So I wonder is there a way I can set Win32 folder and its subfolders, binaries as content of my new UWP project - I expect that will do what I manually did.

Comment: Ok. I've found a question which answers how to set the build action of a whole folder, I've updated my answer accordingly