# In Visual Studio 2017 (new csproj format), how can I set the Build Action for an entire folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, csproj

Basically, I want everything in my "Resources" folder to be an EmbeddedResource.

This question is perfect, but the question there is about the old csproj format. [In Visual Studio, how can I set the Build Action for an entire folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059562/in-visual-studio-how-can-i-set-the-build-action-for-an-entire-folder)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, in the .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```